# PHP database connection inside if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a database if a condition inside an if statement is met:

```
if ($check == 1){
require_once('Connections/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database_lg, $lg);
$query = "SELECT token FROM tbltokens WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $lg) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

It works just fine if I put this same code outside the if statement. As soon as I wrap it in the if statement I get the error: "Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in..." The error applies to lines 2 and 4 in the code.

Notes:

1. I found a similar question where the solution was to require the database connection inside the if statement, which I have done.
2. I realize that mysql_* functions are deprecated. The are tons of mysql_* functions on this site which I have to live with for a while longer.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
connect.php mentioned in the code above looks like this:

```
$hostname_lg = "xxx";
$database_lg = "xxx";
$username_lg = "xxx";
$password_lg = "xxx";
$lg = mysql_pconnect($hostname_lg, $username_lg, $password_lg)
or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

This may not be very relevant though as the connection succeeds when the if statement isn't there. It only fails when inside an if statement as in the example.

Comment: where come $database_lg, $lg values ?

Comment: put the full code in the question please, or more code to give us context

Comment: Do `var_dump($database_lg, $lg);` inside if.

Comment: usually all `require_once` are placed on the top of file, but not somewhere in the code text

Comment: as @andre commented: put full fragment of your code. My guess: you are doing this `if` inside some function. and you already called `connect.php` somewhere else. so namespace agreement is broken and `$database_lg, $lg` variables are out of current namespace. so to verify my theory you can simply replace `require_once` to `include`. everything should work. But your design is really bad then :-)

Comment: @Alex, correct. I put it inside a very long function without realizing it. Thanks. (Really bad design? Definitely :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your if statement inside a function? Each function has its own scope in php. The error you're receiving is making it seem as the parameters you pass in, `$database_lg, $lg` are not defined, meaning they're probably out of scope. You should  make sure the variables `$database_lg, $lg` are visible by calling `global`:

```
if ($check == 1){
    global $database_lg; 
    global $lg;
    ...
}
```

Also, put `require_once` at the top of your code(not in the if statement).

Comment: I was about to say it's not in a function, but I checked and it is. Well called. I moved it out of the function and it works. Many thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. You can keep it in the function if you need to, just be sure to call `global` on each of the `$lg` variables at the beginning of the function definition, like I did above(Doesn't need to be in the `if` statement though, as `if` statement blocks don't have their own scope).